# How to Upload file using rest API in robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, rest, python-requests, robotframework

Not able to upload file/send multipart/form-data using robot framework's requests library.

```
 ${headers}  multipart/form-data
   ${file_data}=    Get Binary File C:\\abc.txt
   ${upload_data}=  multipart form data

  ${resp}=  RequestsLibrary.Post Request    session URL ${upload_data}  ${headers}      ${file_data}
```

Answer (score -3):

Selenium2Library provides Choose File keyword for the same.

It takes two arguments, first is locator for the button and second is path to the file which needs to be uploaded.

e.g.

choose file xpath=.//div/input  ${TEMPDIR}${/}file_pa.csv